# Tomcat6 connect to mySQL problems

Tags: java, mysql, apache, tomcat

I've followed another stackover flow thread to get to this point, it was this one here:

[Tomcat6 MySql JDBC Datasource configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2485006/tomcat6-mysql-jdbc-datasource-configuration)

The problem I have is that the line that goes:

```
Connection conn = ds.getConnection();
```

from this block:

```
Context initCtx = new InitialContext();
Context envCtx = (Context) initCtx.lookup("java:comp/env");
DataSource ds = (DataSource) envCtx.lookup("jdbc/TestDB");

Connection conn = ds.getConnection();
... use this connection to access the database ...
conn.close();
```

Eclipse gives me the error getConnection() is undefined for the type DataSource.

Its solution is to do this:

```
    Connection conn = ((java.sql.Statement) ds).getConnection();
```

No tutorials show the need to do this, and its not working when I do that. I'm using mySQL jar named, `mysql-connector-java-5.1.18-bin`  I've used it with RMI before but never Tomcat, is it the correct type for use with Tomcat?

TIA

Comment: Did you import `DataSource` from the right package in your import statement? Sometimes in Eclipse you may inadvertently select the wrong one when organising imports. What is the full package name for this class in your `import` block?

Comment: There is no way a DataSource can be a Statement. You just imported the wrong DataSource type.

Comment: I did JB, sorted now. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I look into the Java API docs http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/ I find the javax.sql.DataSource interface with a getConnection() method. I assume your DataSource to be something else than one implementing the javax.sql.DataSource interface. What "DataSource" is imported?

Comment: Sorry, are you saying I have the wrong JRE. I've tried switching it other JDK's but still the same. 

The datasource imported is:
 @Resource(name="jdbc/TestDB")
 public DataSource ds;

Comment: As long as you are using JDK1.4 or higher which you should using tomcat5+ it is the right JDK. Actually I wanted to Know the "import"-Statement on top of your java-File. It should read "import javax.sql.DataSource". If there is any other DataSource imported, that is the problem as far as I can say with the information provided.

Comment: Thanks Rupi, there was another DataSource imported, switched it over and the errors gone. Thanks very much.